# Concatenation in scheme

Tags: scheme

I have the following code:

```
(define rest '(((di (a) (b c)) (sh (b) (e d))) ((al (a) (b)))))
(define first '((di (a) (5)) (sh (b) (3))))
```

I want to get the following list:

```
(((di (a) (5)) (sh (b) (3))) ((di (a) (b c)) (sh (b) (e d))) ((al (a) (b)))))
```

meaning, add the list `first`, to be the first element in rest.

When I do `append`, it gives me:

```
((di (a) (5)) (sh (b) (3)) ((di (a) (b c)) (sh (b) (e d))) ((al (a) (b))))
```

And any other library function, or function that I try to do, didn't help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Append` takes two *lists* and puts them together. Given that you have a `first` and a `rest`, you probably want `cons`. `Cons` takes an *element* and prepends it to a list. In this case, the element is `first` and the list is `rest`. So you want something like

```
(cons first rest)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not a good idea to use `first` and `rest` as names for your lists, since they're predefined procedures in some versions of scheme (Racket, for instance) and you'd be redefining them.

A simple `cons` will do the trick, as you can see below:

```
(define fst '((di (a) (5)) (sh (b) (3))))
(define rst '(((di (a) (b c)) (sh (b) (e d))) ((al (a) (b)))))

(cons fst rst)
> (((di (a) (5)) (sh (b) (3))) ((di (a) (b c)) (sh (b) (e d))) ((al (a) (b))))
```

It works because the list you want to obtain is simply `rst` but with a new element, `fst` (a list) at the beginning, whereas you'd typically use `append` when you want to add the elements of one list at the end of another list.

Comment: Standard Scheme does not have `first` and `rest`; it uses `car` and `cdr`. Some implementations, like Racket, do have `first` and `rest`, so for avoiding confusion, it's still good to avoid reusing those names. But it's not correct to say that they're "predefined procedures in Scheme".